# How to add a line in the middle of the program in TI-Basic Editor?

Tags: basic, texas-instruments, ti-basic

I am writing a simple Pong game in TI-Basic but the editor won't let me insert a line into the code I've already written.

For example

```
print "Hello world"
<--Where I want to insert the code
print "hello again"
x = 5
```

If I try to insert code it simply writes over previous code, I cannot create a new line.

Comment: There is presumably an "insert" key (possibly a secondary function) that inserts a new line.

Answer (score 11):

Are you coding on the TI-84 calculator? If so, all you have to do is press "2nd" and then "DEL" (to the left of the arrow-pad). You will note the blue text, "INS", above the "DEL" key.  Then simply press ENTER to add a new line.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it didn't work at first, combined it with pressing enter and it worked.

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck with TI-Basic

Answer (score 5):

There is a relevant section on page 511 of [this TI-83 manual](http://ef.engr.utk.edu/ef152-2014-08/ti/ti83p-manual.pdf).

> ## Inserting and Deleting Command Lines
>
> To insert a new command
>   line anywhere in the program, place the cursor where you want the new
>   line, press <kbd>2nd</kbd> <kbd>INS</kbd>, and then press
>   <kbd>ENTER</kbd> . A colon indicates a new line.
>
> To delete a command line, place the cursor on the line, press
>   <kbd>CLEAR</kbd> to clear all instructions and expressions on the
>   line, and then press <kbd>DEL</kbd> to delete the command line,
>   including the colon.